# Image slider to display at the very top of home page

Tags: headers

I've installed a slider, however I want it to sit at the very top of my page under the navigation. However I'm not sure how to do this.

```
        <?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package GovPress
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js' ); ?>"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

        <body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">

    <?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>


    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding col-width">
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
                </a>
            <?php endif; // End header image check. ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>
```

Comment: okay, my code is in the question. That is what is in my header.php in my childtheme, i'm using govpress wordpress theme and its the sp responsive header image slider

Comment: Welcome to the stack network. When you add code to your question/answer, you should have a look at the top of the editor, there is a `{}` sign. Highlight your code that you pasted to your question/answer, and click on the `{}` sign. This will put your code in a code block as you can see what I did in my edit

Comment: The nav menu isn't in there, it could be in page.php

Look for wp_nav_menu and add the slider code under that

Comment: You might want to consider using a theme like Twenty Twelve instead.

Comment: home-page.php is in the templates folder in your theme

Comment: Note that wordpress.stackexchange.com do not handle questions concerning third party plugins and themes. As these required detailed knowledge of the workings of those plugins and themes, support is difficult and with thousands of plugins and themes available such knowledge is very specialized. Please consult the appropriate support forum for the plugin or theme in question. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help

Answer (score 1):

[image]
**Note:** The slider only displays if you install the plugin and use the correct slider I.D in the code for the template tag after creating a slider and adding images. The screenshot i posted below proves my code works.

Here's the header.php code with the template tag for the slider on line 36

```
<?php
/**
 * The Header for our theme.
 *
 * Displays all of the <head> section and everything up till <div id="content">
 *
 * @package GovPress
 */
?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title><?php wp_title( '|', true, 'right' ); ?></title>
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="<?php echo esc_url( get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/html5.js' ); ?>"></script>
<![endif]-->
<?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">

    <?php do_action( 'before' ); ?>

    <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation" role="navigation">
        <div class="col-width">
            <h1 class="menu-toggle"><?php _e( 'Menu', 'govpress' ); ?></h1>
            <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'govpress' ); ?></a>

            <?php wp_nav_menu( array('theme_location' => 'primary', 'menu_class' => 'nav-menu' ) ); ?>
        </div>
    </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
<?php if ( is_front_page && function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) ) { soliloquy( 'demo', 'slug' ); } ?>
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
        <div class="site-branding col-width">
            <?php if ( get_header_image() ) : ?>
                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home">
                    <img src="<?php header_image(); ?>" width="<?php echo get_custom_header()->width; ?>" height="<?php echo get_custom_header()->height; ?>" alt="">
                </a>
            <?php endif; // End header image check. ?>
            <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
            <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
        </div>
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <?php if ( is_page_template('templates/home-page.php') ) {
        get_template_part( 'templates/above', 'home-page' );
    } ?>

    <div class="col-width">
        <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

Assumes you're using the Soliloquy Lite slider plugin:

```
<?php if ( is_front_page && function_exists( 'soliloquy' ) ) { soliloquy( 'demo', 'slug' ); } ?>
```

In the Govpress theme there's a home-page.php file you might want to paste the template tag for your slider into.

Not sure why the theme Developer doesn't include a front-page.php or home.php file in the root directory of the theme rather than the way its been structured.

Comment: thanks Brad, that worked a charm. the only problem i have now is on full page the slider is not centred across the page. it works great for responsive.

Comment: You could increase the width of the images in the slider settings or use CSS. The plugin Dev does offer tutorials for this on his site.

Comment: i've tried increasing the width in the slider settings but nothing changes. The tutorials are not helping.

Comment: Please consult the plugin Developer. They are amongst the best tutorials any slider plugin Dev offers. Or you may consider the Developer of your theme as it may be the theme causing issues which is why i suggested you try the Twenty Twelve theme.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help Brad. I'll try that. Done way too much on the current theme to start over again.